# Mage registry key "_singleton/packagename_LoyaltyOptin_Model_Observer" already exists

Tags: magento

I have a problem with my observer. It is not found when event is fired.
Here is the config.xml:

```
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <packagename_loyaltyoptincheckout>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>packagename_LoyaltyOptin_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>getLoyaltyOptIn</method>
                </packagename_loyaltyoptincheckout>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
```

Observer is stored in packagename_LoyaltyOptin_Model_Observer.

Compilation is disabled and was disabled when installing extension.

Tried clearing var/cache.

Comment: you are using same register key at once time “_singleton/packagename_LoyaltyOptin_Model_Observer”

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a captial letter, my module name had a capital letter in it and my xml did not. Thanks